# username constant returning null?

Tags: javascript, ejs

So i have an EJS that i use for generating the interface for CRUDS operations on my web app,
on this specific problem the table for existing users in the DB is rendered properly with the correct usernames and their corresponding roles, one row per user is generated and when the page in rendered and it does show the correct amount of existing users.

im an at a loss on when i try to retrieve the username again that it comes up null,
currently there are 10 accounts in the DB and the ejs does create ten table rows.

The EJS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/Manage.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/css/all.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="../Images/Seal.ico">
        <script src="../Scripts/Manage.js"></script>
        <title>Manage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Header-Container">
            <header class="Header">
                <img src="../Images/SchoolLogo.png">
                <div class="Search-Bar">
                        <form role="search" action="/search/" class="search"></form>
                    <div class="Search-Container">
                            <input type="text" class="Search-Field" id="SearchField" placeholder="Search">
                            <button type="submit" class="Search-Button" id="SubmitButton"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
                        </form>
                        <div class="Header-Nav">
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="new">New</li>
                                    <li id="articles">Articles</li>
                                    <li id="books">Books</li>
                                    <li id="about">About Us</li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <a href="../Teacher-Pages/Manage.html"  class="BtnAnchor"><button id="Upload" class="UploadBtn"><i class="fa-2x fa-solid fa-upload"></i></button></a>
                    <a href="" class="BtnAnchor"><button class="AccountBtn"><i class=" fa-2x fa-solid fa-user"></i></button></a>
                    <button id="Logout" class="LogoutBtn"><i class="fa-2x fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket"></i></button>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="User-Section">
            <div class="Table-Container">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                <table class="User-Table">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
        
                    <% users.forEach(user => { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Username-Field"><%= user.username %></td>
                            <td><%= user.role %></td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="DeleteBtn" data-username="<%= user.username %>" id="deleteBtn">A</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                     <% }); %>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Side-Panel">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Front End Js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.DeleteBtn');

    deleteButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
            const username = event.target.getAttribute('data-username');
            console.log(username); //returns null
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`/api/delete-user/${username}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    event.target.closest('tr').remove();
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to delete user');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what about `const username = event.target.dataset.username;` - or,`const username = button.dataset.username;`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you `const username = event.target.dataset.username;` in place of  `const username = event.target.getAttribute('data-username');` fixed it and allowed me to get the username

Answer (score 0):

I know that you already have a solution to the problem, but you don't need an event listener for every button. Just wrap everything in a form and let all the delete buttons have the type of `button` (this will not submit anything). Let's say that you update the table with the next 10 users you don't need to add event listeners again.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.forms.form01.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let name = e.target.name;
    switch (name) {
      case 'delete':
        const username = e.target.dataset.username;
        // do stuff to delete
        console.log(username);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <button type="button" name="delete" data-username="a1">Delete a1</button>
  <button type="button" name="delete" data-username="a2">Delete a2</button>
</form>
```